# Pyinstaller is not recognizing Nornir and the script crashes

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to make an exe. file of my script which is using Nornir automation framework but  it is giving the following exception. Can anyone help me in fixing this issue?

```
  File "cli.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "import_functions.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\nornir\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 481, in get_distribution
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 357, in get_provider
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 900, in require
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'nornir' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[50524] Failed to execute script cli ~~~
```